# No unused kernels in /boot but still 100% full

Tags: boot, partitioning

My /boot partition is "full" but actually only the used kernel is inside.
I found similar questions and I followed the instructions for unused kernels removal.
I am using 3.2.0-58-generic-pae and I've cleared all the rest with 
`sudo rm -rf /boot/*-3.2.0-{29,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,44,45,48,49,52,53,56,57}-*`
I also performed 
`apt-get clean` , `apt-get remove`, `apt-get autoremove` but nothing changed. The /boot is still showing 100% full although there is only 1 kernel inside. 
Any ideas?

The outputs of: `ls /boot ; df -h ; df -i` :

```
ls /boot/

abi-3.2.0-58-generic-pae         lost+found
config-3.2.0-58-generic-pae      memtest86+.bin
extlinux                         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
grub                             System.map-3.2.0-58-generic-pae
initrd.img-3.2.0-58-generic-pae  vmlinuz-3.2.0-58-generic-pae

df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda12      9.7G  379M  8.9G   5% /
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           797M  1.2M  796M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  192K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda11       14G  163M   13G   2% /tmp
/dev/sda1       461M  445M     0 100% /boot
/dev/sda6        56G   39G   15G  73% /home
/dev/sda9        19G  172M   18G   1% /opt
/dev/sda7        19G  4.4G   14G  26% /usr
/dev/sda8        19G  176M   18G   1% /usr/local
/dev/sda10      9.2G  922M  7.9G  11% /var

df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda12      644640   9557  635083    2% /
udev            208092    587  207505    1% /dev
tmpfs           211750    542  211208    1% /run
none            211750      3  211747    1% /run/lock
none            211750      9  211741    1% /run/shm
/dev/sda11      915712     38  915674    1% /tmp
/dev/sda1       121920    457  121463    1% /boot
/dev/sda6      3662848  40036 3622812    2% /home
/dev/sda9      1220608     11 1220597    1% /opt
/dev/sda7      1220608 511759  708849   42% /usr
/dev/sda8      1220608    113 1220495    1% /usr/local
/dev/sda10      610800   9269  601531    2% /var
```

`ls -l /boot
total 22369
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   804938 Dec  3 20:02 abi-3.2.0-58-generic-pae
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   147576 Dec  3 20:02 config-3.2.0-58-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     1024 Feb 12 08:29 extlinux
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     7168 Apr  2 21:21 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14217519 Apr  2 21:31 initrd.img-3.2.0-58-generic-pae
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Oct 13  2012 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176764 Nov 27  2011 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178944 Nov 27  2011 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  2321986 Dec  3 20:02 System.map-3.2.0-58-generic-pae
-rw------- 1 root root  5031904 Dec  3 20:02 vmlinuz-3.2.0-58-generic-pae`

Comment: Open a terminal type `ls /boot` and paste the results in your question.

Comment: Please add the output of `df -h` and `df -i` to your question.

Comment: Did you run `df -h` immediately after removing unused kernels in  your `/boot`?

Comment: Did you empty root's trash which is well hidden? And sometimes even with sudo it does not work and you have to take ownership of trash to let you delete it. But be very careful of changing ownership or permissions of any system partition.

Comment: Root's trash? No.. How?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `ls -l /boot`?

Comment: `sudo ls -a /root/.local/share
.  ..  .converted-launchers  recently-used.xbel  zeitgeist`

Comment: @Jobin Posted it.

Comment: Where is root's trash?! There isn't a trash folder in /root/.local/share

Answer (score 1):

There was a `.Trash` folder in `/boot` containing all the deleted files. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> and I've got 450MB freed.
Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the filesystem cache and buffers after you have removed files for `df -h` and similar commands which provide filesystem statistics for them to provide the correct data.

To clear the filesystem cache and buffers you need to run

```
sync
```

on a terminal and then recheck the stats. You could also perform a reboot to clear the cache.

Refer to [the manual page of sync](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) for more information.

Comment: Freshly rebooted, still the same.